# How to use scrollIntoView with overflow:hidden and without scrolling the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to use scrollIntoView on container which has `overflow:hidden` and it shouldn't scroll the page?

Here is an example: at the bottom of the page text in container `<div class="cnt'>` which has fixed width and overflow hidden. I want to scroll items in this container without scrolling the page.

At the top of the page two buttons to scroll to first and last element. If i click on button it will scroll text in the container and scroll to that container at the bottom of the page.

I can't use scrollLeft because overflow is hidden. :(

Does anybody know how to solve it?

```js
const cnt = document.querySelector('.cnt')
const spanElements = cnt.querySelectorAll('span');
const lastSpan = spanElements[spanElements.length - 1]
const firstSpan = spanElements[0]

lastSpan.scrollIntoView()

const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button')) 
const [buttonToFirstEl, buttonToLastEl] = buttons;

buttonToFirstEl.onclick = function() {
  firstSpan.scrollIntoView()
}

buttonToLastEl.onclick = function() {
  lastSpan.scrollIntoView()
}
```

```css
.cnt {
  width: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 8px;
  border: solid #ccc 1px;
}

.filler {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: dashed 2px #ccc;
  margin: 20px;
}

.root {
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <button id="button">scroll to first element</button>
  <button id="button">scroll to last element</button>
  <div class="filler">
  </div>
  <div class="filler">
  </div>
  <div class="filler">
  </div>
  <div class="filler">
  </div>
  <div class="cnt">
    <span>
      first:tessst
    </span>
    <span>
      2:dddd
    </span>
    <span>
      3:cccddd
    </span>
    <span>
      4:rreeee
    </span>
    <span>
      last:dddrreddd
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/geeny273/pen/bGpxYqG

Comment: are you want to make div .root has Y scroll with overflow hidden right

Comment: You want only the default behavior of scrollIntoView or to be able to pass the block-inline rules as well? Also, do you care about writing directions or treating all as left to right top to bottom is fine?

Comment: @OuchaneCC I want to scroll elements inside <div class="cnt">. .root element used to show that page is scrolling too

Comment: @Kaiido for this example default behavior is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scrollLeft` and `scrollTop` work well with `overflow:hidden`. I check `scrollLeft` property on first span element instead of its container

changing `scrollLeft` on parent element of span, solve this issue

```
 firstSpan.parentElement.scrollLeft = 0;
```

```js
const cnt = document.querySelector('.cnt')
const spanElements = cnt.querySelectorAll('span');
const lastSpan = spanElements[spanElements.length - 1]
const firstSpan = spanElements[0]

lastSpan.scrollIntoView()

const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button')) 
const [buttonToFirstEl, buttonToLastEl] = buttons;

buttonToFirstEl.onclick = function() {
  firstSpan.parentElement.scrollLeft = 0;
}

buttonToLastEl.onclick = function() {
  const cnt = lastSpan.parentElement;
  cnt.scrollLeft = cnt.scrollWidth;
}
```

```css
.cnt {
  width: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 8px;
  border: solid #ccc 1px;
}

.filler {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: dashed 2px #ccc;
  margin: 20px;
}

.root {
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <button id="button">scroll to first element</button>
  <button id="button">scroll to last element</button>
  <div class="filler">
  </div>
  <div class="filler">
  </div>
  <div class="filler">
  </div>
  <div class="filler">
  </div>
  <div class="cnt">
    <span>
      first:tessst
    </span>
    <span>
      2:dddd
    </span>
    <span>
      3:cccddd
    </span>
    <span>
      4:rreeee
    </span>
    <span>
      last:dddrreddd
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want scrolled element in .cnt class

[image]

- you need to style every span in .cnt

.cnt span{

> ```
>      /* relative + block for make elements solid & listed*/
>       position : relative;
>       display : block;
> ```

> ```
>       color: red;
>       font-size : 16px;
> ```

}

- and in .cnt parent you need to defined height for making scroll working

.cnt {

```
  width: 90px;

  /* for example 28px */
  height : 28px;

  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 4px;
  border: solid black 1px;

  /* overflow y or x for making scroll*/
  overflow-y : scroll;
```

}

- i hope this steps help you

Answer (score 0):

To get this correctly, (i.e with support for all writing-mode, direction and block-inline options) you'd basically have to rewrite [scrollIntoView](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#element-scrolling-members) from scratch, while omitting the loop that goes up the tree of scrolling-boxes. This is not a trivial task.

If you don't need a bullet proof solution though, you can simply get the nearest scrolling-box and check by how much it should be scrolled to show the start of your element:

```js
const cnt = document.querySelector('.cnt')
const spanElements = cnt.querySelectorAll('span');
const lastSpan = spanElements[spanElements.length - 1]
const firstSpan = spanElements[0]



const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button')) 
const [buttonToFirstEl, buttonToLastEl] = buttons;

buttonToFirstEl.onclick = function() {
  scrollIntoParentView( firstSpan );
}

buttonToLastEl.onclick = function() {
  scrollIntoParentView( lastSpan );
}

function scrollIntoParentView( elem, options ) {
  const directions = getSimpleScrollIntoViewDirections( elem, options );
  const left = directions.inline_direction || 0;
  const top = directions.block_direction || 0;
  const new_options = {
    left,
    top,
    behavior: (options && options.behavior) || "auto"
  };
  directions.scrolling_box.scrollBy( new_options );
}
function getSimpleScrollIntoViewDirections( elem, { block = "start", inline = "start" } = {} ) {

  const element_bbox = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  const scrolling_box = getNearestScrollingBox( elem );
  const scrolling_box_bbox = scrolling_box.getBoundingClientRect();

  const block_direction = Math.round( element_bbox.top - scrolling_box_bbox.top);
  const inline_direction = Math.round( element_bbox.left - scrolling_box_bbox.left);

  return {
    scrolling_box,
    block_direction,
    inline_direction
  };
}

function getNearestScrollingBox( elem ) {
  if( !elem.isConnected ) { return null; }
  const elem_computed_styles = getComputedStyle( elem );
  // not in specs, but that seems to be what browser implementations do
  if( elem_computed_styles.getPropertyValue( 'position' ) === "fixed" ) {
    return null;
  }
  const scrolling_box = elem.parentElement;
  if( !scrolling_box ) {
    return elem === document.scrollingElement ? null : document.scrollingElement;
  }
  const computed_styles = getComputedStyle( scrolling_box );
  const scroll_x = computed_styles.getPropertyValue( "overflow-x");
  const scroll_y = computed_styles.getPropertyValue( "overflow-y");
  if(
    (scroll_x === 'clip' && scroll_y === 'clip') ||
    (scrolling_box.offsetHeight <= scrolling_box.scrollingHeight) ||
    (scrolling_box.offsetWidth <= scrolling_box.scrollingWidth)
   ) {
    return getNearestScrollingBox( scrolling_box );
  }
  return scrolling_box;
}
```

```css
.cnt {
  width: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 8px;
  border: solid #ccc 1px;
}

.filler {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: dashed 2px #ccc;
  margin: 20px;
}

.root {
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <button id="button">scroll to first element</button>
  <button id="button">scroll to last element</button>
  <div class="filler">
  </div>
  <div class="filler">
  </div>
  <div class="filler">
  </div>
  <div class="filler">
  </div>
  <div class="cnt">
    <span>
      first:tessst
    </span>
    <span>
      2:dddd
    </span>
    <span>
      3:cccddd
    </span>
    <span>
      4:rreeee
    </span>
    <span>
      last:dddrreddd
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```